# What are the rules governing duplicate cards in Duels of the Planeswalkers 2013?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013

I just fought two consecutive opponents in the campaign that I thought had pretty odd decks:

- **Face of the Ghoulcaller:** A black deck that had at least 9 *Horrifying Revelation* cards, all cast in a row.
- **Disturbing the Nest:** A white deck that had 12 *Suntail Hawk* cards, again, all cast in a row.

Granted, it's been a while since I played the physical card game, but I could've sworn there was a restriction of four non-land, non-legendary cards per deck. I don't recall ever facing an opponent with that many duplicate cards in *DotP* or *DotP 2012*, though.

So what gives? Are the rules of deck creation different for Magic 2013 or even just for  *Duels of the Planeswalkers 2013*? If so, what are the rules?

Or are computer opponents just allowed to "cheat" and create cheese decks like these?

Comment: FAE's answer is correct. Encounters are exempt from the rule. If we're talking the actual card game, the only way to avoid the 4 card maximum is with Ravenous Rats. Just thought that was a fun bit of information.

Comment: @Fluttershy relentless rats, not ravenous :)

Comment: @hammythepig Oh yeah. Got my Rats mixed up. =P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The opponents you are facing are special Encounters in the campaign. When you did your first encounter, there should have been a popup telling you that Encounters are specifically designed this way in order to help you improve your skill at facing specific strategies. These matches are specifically labeled with **Encounter** in front of the name of the match, like **Encounter: Disturbing the Nest** and **Encounter: Face of the Ghoulcaller**.

Encounters will *always* play out the exact same way. For example, during the Encounter *Stampede!*, the AI will always play a Willow Elf on Turn 1, followed by a Runeclaw Bear on Turn 2, and so on.

Encounters also, as you have noted, have decks that are exempt from the limit of 4 of the same type of card.

The Planeswalkers you face in the campaign and other opponents, like Odric, have decks that *are* subject to the 4 card rule. Note that the game with them will also be different each time you play, in contrast to the Encounters, which always play with the same order, use the same strategies and same cards.

Comment: Hm, I don't recall getting a popup like that on the iPad version of the game. But at any rate, thanks: that explains a lot.

Answer (score -3):

There is a game bug. You can only a max of 4 of the same cards per deck

Comment: I don't think it's a bug: [a quick search for YouTube videos for Face of the Ghoulcaller](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=magic+2013+face+of+the+ghoulcaller&search_filter=0) shows similar matches to what I had with nobody commenting on it being a bug.